# Imagen de avatar desaparecida

Tags: soporte, perfil

¿Por qué ha desaparecido la imagen de mi avatar? He vuelto a subirla y sigue sin verse. ¿Ha habido algún cambio respecto a las imágenes?

Comment: No que yo sepa. Que tenías de imagen de perfil? Es posible que tuviera copyright o algo asi?

Comment: Yo veo tu imagen de perfil. Quizás fue algo de un momento o una falla de tu equipo/navegador/conexión

Comment: Debería verse el smile con la gotita de sangre del comediante de la película de Watchmen. Si se trata de algún tema de infracción de copyright.... deberían notificar algo ¿no?

Comment: El perfil solo pueden cambiártelo los moderadores o los Community Manager (además de tú, claro está). En ambos casos queda registro, así que si fuera el caso simplemente sería mirarlo. Dicho lo cual, me extrañaría mucho que algo así se hiciera con una imagen no hiriente.

Comment: Acabo de revisar y no se aprecia ninguna edición del perfil hecha por nadie desde el año pasado...es extraño. La imagen la subes desde tu equipo? O la estás enlazando desde algun sitio? @fedorqui lo de "imagen no hiriente" es bastante subjetivo, y algunos moderadores y/o CM pueden tener una sensibilidad diferente en cuanto a lo que es o no ofensivo...

Comment: @Pikoh gracias por revisarlo! Claro, por eso debe dejarse para casos extremos que seguramente nadie dudaría en señalar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que ya se lo que pasó.

Cuando creé mi perfil en stackoverflow por alguno razón que desconozco estaba relacionado con mi cuenta de facebook. Hace unos meses borré mi cuenta de facebook. Hoy me fijé un poco mejor y parece que una de las opciones de subir imagen es coger la de tu facebook, la he desmarcado, subido otra vez la imagen de mi avatar y listo.

Todo aparentemente solucionado. Gracias por las aportaciones ;-)